# Realtime audio playing on headphones while recording audio from bluetooth

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming, android-bluetooth, headset

I am recording audio from Bluetooth headsets. I want to play this recorded audio in real time on my wired headphones. How can I direct my audio to wired headphones.

I am using below code for directing audio.

```
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
mAudioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);
mAudioManager.setRouting(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, AudioManager.ROUTE_HEADSET,AudioManager.ROUTE_BLUETOOTH_SCO );
```

Above code works on android version 5 but does not work on android version 7 and above.

Need Help in:

1. why it is not working in new android versions
2. How can I make it work on newer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using below code. It works perfect for old versions but audio directed to wired headphones in newer version is noisy. I will try to solve the noise problem and will update the answer.

```
AudioDeviceInfo[] devices = mAudioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);
    if (devices  != null){
      for (AudioDeviceInfo device : devices)
         if (device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET || device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES) {
            audioTrack.setPreferredDevice(device);
            mAudioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);
            mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
          }
     }
```